Click/tap on the hamburger button in a collapsable navbar does not work and the nav-items do not appear
Given the following nav in my rails 7 app using bootstrap 5.3.3 when the hamburger button does appear as intended in mobile resolution and when I click/tap the button nothing happens (no behaviour) and the expected nav-items do not appear.
1. Navbar according to bootstrap 5.3.3 classes :
<header class ="mb-5 header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark
              sticky-top border-bottom border-body" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "WCSLUX", root_path, id: "logo", class: "navbar-brand"  %>
    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav" class="navbar-toggler">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home",  root_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Westies", westies_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Community", community_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
</header>

Gem file
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

gem "rails",           "7.0.4"
gem "bootstrap"
gem "sassc-rails",     "2.1.2"
gem "sprockets-rails", "3.4.2"
gem "importmap-rails", "1.1.0"
gem "turbo-rails",     "1.1.1"
gem "stimulus-rails",  "1.0.4"
gem "jbuilder",        "2.11.5"
gem "puma",            "5.6.4"
gem "bootsnap",        "1.12.0", require: false


group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
  gem "debug",   "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :production do
  gem "pg", "1.3.5"
  gem "aws-sdk-s3", "1.114.0", require: false
end

2. importmap.rb
pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true  
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true

3. app/javascript/application.js
//= require popper  
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

import "popper"  
import "bootstrap"

4.app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images  
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css

5. initialisers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = "1.0"  
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.js popper.js )

When I click/tap the hamburger button I should see the expected nav-items on the right of the nav bar :
   
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home",  root_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Westies", westies_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Community", community_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path,
        class: "nav-link" %></li>
      

I would like to avoid the cdn script kind of solution. Also, I want my nav items to appear to the right of the nav bar.

It is a long time I haven't used Bootstrap but I suggest you open your browser developper tools. On chrome & Firefox: right-click -> inspect. Then CTRL+SHIFT+C to locate your elements on the DOM. You can click on the burger then see your code in the Inspector/Elements tab in the Inspect tool panel. Watch what happens to your  elements when you click the burger. It should change the visibility by adding or removing a class to their wrapper. This will give you hints on what happens.

Open up the developer tools but your first stop should be to check the sources tab and see if the expected assets are actually loaded. Next check the console for errors. Then check the event handlers tab for the element - bootstrap should register a click handler.
